# Solving $\ln(x) = W(x)$ and its continued variant

Tags: number-theory

I've been "interested" in the Lambert W function for a while now. (Will use $W(x)$ instead of $W_n(x)$ as suggested by Wikipedia, for simplicity's sake).

Of course, the solution for $$\ln(x) = W(x)$$ is fairly simple, since $$e^{\ln(x)} = e^{W(x)} \longrightarrow x = e^{W(x)} $$ and by substituting $x = te^t$ $$te^t = e^t \longrightarrow t = 1.$$

For the second variant, $\ln(\ln(x)) = W(W(x))$, I can still manage to solve it, but I need some verification.
My try:
$$e^{e^{\ln(\ln(x))}} = e^{e^{W(W(x)}} \longrightarrow x = e^{e^{W(W(x))}}$$
and by substituting $x = ue^u e^{ue^u}$, we have $$ue^u e^{ue^u} = e^{e^u} \longrightarrow ue^u e^u e^{e^u} = e^{e^u} \longrightarrow ue^{2u} = 1$$
Letting $u = \frac{W(y)}{y}$, we have $$\frac{W(y)}{y} e^{\frac{2W(y)}{y}}=1$$
and letting $y = 2k$, we have $$\frac{W(2k)}{k} e^{\frac{W(2k)}{k}}=2 \longrightarrow W(\frac{W(2k)}{k} e^\frac{W(2k)}{k})=W(2) \longrightarrow \frac{W(2k)}{k} = W(2)$$ (please forgive me if there was any typo, the MathJax was kinda chaotic.)

Thus we have $$u = \frac{W(y)}{y} = \frac{W(2k)}{2k} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{W(2k)}{k} = \frac{W(2)}{2}$$
and $$x = ue^u e^{ue^u} = \frac{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}W(2)}{2\sqrt{W(2)}}}}{2\sqrt{W(2)}}$$

Of course, I'm more interested in the general problem. I cannot find a solution to $W(W(W(...W(x)...))) = \ln(\ln(\ln(...\ln(x)...)))$ , or if phrased more mathematically:

> Let $f_1(n)=\ln(n)$ and $g_1(n) = W(n)$. Also, let $f_k(n) = \ln(f_{k-1}(n))$ and $g_k(n) = W(g_{k-1}(n))$ for all positive integers $k$. Find the solution to $f_m(n) = g_m(n)$ for all positive integers $m$, in terms of $m$.

My conjecture is that the answer is something similar to $$n = \frac{\sqrt{m}e^{\frac{\sqrt{m}W(m)}{m\sqrt{W(m)}}}}{m\sqrt{W(m)}}$$ with (probably) more iterations of the same thing. Can anybody verify this?

Comment: You can use the command \ln to get the proper $\ln$ instead of the ugly-looking $ln$. Note also that $$
\frac{{\sqrt m e^{\frac{{\sqrt m W(m)}}{{m\sqrt {W(m)} }}} }}{{m\sqrt {W(m)} }} = \frac{{e^{\sqrt {\frac{{W(m)}}{m}} } }}{{\sqrt {mW(m)} }}.
$$

Comment: Thank you Gary! I didn't know this before.